# How can I conditionally hide all the child elements using Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I would like to conditionally hide all the child elements of a div. Currently, I am hiding each of them but it's so repetitive and the code is ugly.

```
<div>
     <div th:hidden="${#lists.size(myObject) == 0}">Hi</div>
     <div th:hidden="${#lists.size(myObject) == 0}">Privet</div>
     <div th:hidden="${#lists.size(myObject) == 0}">Hola</div>     
</div>
```

I have tried applying conditions to the parent to see if it would hide child elements, but it doesn't.

```
<div th:hidden="${#lists.size(myObject) == 0}">
     <div>Hi</div>
     <div>Privet</div>
     <div>Hola</div>     
</div>
```

Please note that I don't want to use `th:if=${#lists.size(myObject) == 0}` because that would make entire elements inaccessible by JavaScript code. I just want to hide them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ID of the div and set its `display` to `none` like so:

```
document.querySelector("#AddIdOfdivHere").style.display="none";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it best to use JavaScript? Is there no Thymeleaf solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div th:style="${#lists.size(myObject) == 0 ? 'display:none;' : 'display:block;'}">
  <div>Hi</div>
  <div>Privet</div>
  <div>Hola</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortuantely it seems like it's only applying the style for itself, not to its children. Great to know that `th:style` existed though!

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a suficient explaination of your possible solution.